# Does a team stop batting if it cannot win?

Tags: cricket

In last night's Scotland-Sri Lanka match, Scotland lost their last wicket after 43.1 overs, 363/9 to 215/10 (43.1).  At that point, averaging just under 5 runs per over, Scotland would have reached a point around the 47th over, where it would have been no longer (realistically) possible to win the match.

For example, say they had not been dismissed in 43.1, and instead scored 5 (more) runs in that over, leading to 220 at 44.0.  They then scored 5 more runs for the next several overs; at 47.0 they have a score of 235.  With 18 balls remaining in 3 overs, they now trail by 128; but even if they hit sixes on every single ball, they could only score 108.  Yes, there might have been extras, but hardly twenty of them.

Had this happened, would they continue to bat (pointlessly)?  (I realize that in some circumstances, total runs scored might factor into tiebreaks for going on, but clearly not in Scotland's case.)  Would it have been by choice (similar to declaring an innings at end in a Test match, though that is usually for the opposite reason) or by rule?

More generally:

In a limited overs match (an ODI or similar), is there a criteria for ending a game prematurely when it is determined to be no longer possible that the team batting second can win?

Comment: And yes, it was not realistically possible for Scotland to win the match when they came to bat (or even to bowl), but here I mean realistically more stringently :)

Comment: It's never impossible for the team batting second to win. The bowling team could suddenly bowl 100 no balls, or give away 100 in overthrows.

Comment: Sure, in theory (as I mention in the question), but in practice more than a few no balls (out of 18 balls!) would not happen in an international match (or similar level).  Hence my curiosity if there is a rule to stop play, or a convention to voluntarily stop play, or not.

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect that as it's a significantly different question.

Comment: My question states that specifically. Read the second to last paragraph.

Comment: The trouble is your last paragraph uses the phrase "no longer possible". As I think we've agreed, that situation never occurs.

Comment: `When it is determined to be`.  Slaughter rules exist in other sports (not typically in adult, international sports, but still) where it is rule-bound determined to be no longer possible - or where the opposing team concedes it is no longer possible, such as often occurs in chess - for one team to win, regardless of technical possibilities.

Comment: Even if there is a rule in ODI (I am not aware of it though), I think the 'Spirit of the Game' addition to the cricket laws would suggest that regardless of the perceived outcome, it would not be in the spirit of the game to not continue play until the last ball.

Comment: In test cricket there is an instance where opposition has refused to continue play and the match was stopped.In a match between Pak and Eng,Pakistan had refused to play the match after the tea break as the result of which the match was awarded to England. more at - http://www.espncricinfo.com/engvpak/engine/match/225258.html

Comment: @NetStarter That's pretty much unrelated. The Pakistan team refused to play in protest at the action of the umpires, not because they thought they had no chance of winning.

Comment: @PhilipKendall yes I know.It is the reference for the case when a match is ended prematurely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ODI regulations specifically prevent a side from declaring, so the option of just stopping batting is not present (see section 14 of [this PDF](http://icc-live.s3.amazonaws.com/cms/media/about_docs/54dad3266e240-CWC2015%20Final%20Update%2028%201%202015.pdf)).

In theory, they could simply walk off the pitch and forfeit, but would be subject to sanctions if that happened, making it incredibly unlikely.

In short, even if you know you cannot win (barring Philip Kendall's scenario in the comments), you play the game to it's conclusion.